# How to fix a drupal (https) website with blocked mixed content

Tags: javascript, iframe, drupal, https, drupal-7

My Drupal e-commerce site is working on https.I want to embed below code to a page.

```
<iframe src="http://files.podsnack.com/......"(not exact code)
```

But src is on http, due to this not able to load the iframe in the page. I am getting below error.

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://files.podsnack.com/iframe/embed.html?hash=avcsgijp&t=1402616221"
carouFredSel: No element found for "#clients-scroller".
plugins... > eval (line 1)

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Note: src will not work on https.
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you cannot load an iframe via http on a https page securely, thus getting the errors. Browsers are beginning to just completely block this now, where as older browsers would just give a warning.

The only way to get it to load is using https for the iframe, or accessing the page via http instead of https.

See this blog post about Firefox introducing the block: https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/

and here's a page about IE blocking mixed content: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2625928

and here's a page about Chrome blocking mixed content or warning about it: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?hl=en

And see this post for a general explanation of the problem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content

Comment: Thanks,The two option will not work here. Iframe URL will not work on https and second option giving session related issues when i try to access this page on http.

Comment: @user3744065 I know it's a bit of a pain sometimes. Caused me a few problems working on a facebook app once, and we pretty much had to give up on what we were attempting to do.

Comment: This is drupal based e-commerce application.

Comment: @user3744065 Yes. I was just referring to a case where I was dealing with mixed content being blocked. Same rules will apply to Drupal and the rest of the web.